# SVG resources? Good forums, help sites, examples?

Tags: svg, forum

I am currently doing a SVG project for school and I was wondering if I could be given any good sites with some awesome SVG examples? I can't even find a forum where I can ask questions specific to SVG.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[w3schools](http://w3schools.com/svg/default.asp) always a good resource.

And I use the drawing program [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org) which can show you the svg too.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a site where I can come up with project ideas and stuff. Currently creating a SVG/JS image gallery.

Answer (score 1):

As Erno says Inkscape and even Adobe Illustrator are good for drawing svg, I think there's app in the Chrome web store that you can use to draw svg in the browser as well.

There are plenty of examples out there:

http://svg-wow.org/ has some really good work.

Raphael is also worth a look as library to get cross-browser support.

And in terms of forums the svg forums there's a yahoo group called svg-developers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [courses](http://www.w3.org/2010/09/intro_svg_course_description.php) offered by the W3C on SVG, and read the [SVG primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html).

A good place for asking questions is e.g stackoverflow (hey, you're here already, good for you!), the #svg channel on the [freenode](http://freenode.net) IRC network and the [svg-developers mailinglist](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/).

If you're looking for examples etc, feel free to have a look through the links [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/links/).

Answer (score -1):

Try pac-n-zoom.com and make animations within minutes. I made this one
http://pac-n-zoom.com/animBeachBike1.svg